# How to encrypt salesforce data

Tags: apex, rest-api, integration, crypto

How to encrypt salesforce data and send it through rest api to third party system?

I need some sample code to get started.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Apex includes the [Crypto](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_crypto.htm) class that:

> Provides methods for creating digests, message authentication codes, and signatures, as well as encrypting and decrypting information.

In addition to all the sample calls in the docuemntation linked above there is also [Using the Apex Crypto Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Crypto_Class), which has further examples.

You could also browse other [crypto](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crypto) question on this site.